# Get number of followers on twitter using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the number of followers on twitter. I successfully managed to get number of followers like so:

```
String followers = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ProfileCanopy-navBar']//li[@class='ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers']//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']")).getText();
```

The problem is that the answer is not the exact number, "4.41M".

The HTML:

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav" data-nav="followers" tabindex="0" data-original-title="4,406,048 Followers">
    <span class="ProfileNav-label">Followers</span>
    <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-is-compact="true">4.41M</span>
</a>
```

I'm trying to get the number "4,406,048" (at the end of attribute a). I looked online for about an hour and didn't find a proper solution. I'm using Selenium with Java and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a strange one. I wrote code that should have pulled the number but it kept returning `null` also. I finally figured out what was going on when I pulled the element and then wrote out the outerHTML. The element was being changed during page load.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://twitter.com/blakeshelton");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[data-nav='followers']")));
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("title"));
```

If you run this code you will get

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-openSignupDialog js-nonNavigable u-textUserColor" title="14,189,678 Followers" data-nav="followers" href="/blakeshelton/followers">
    <span class="ProfileNav-label">Followers</span>
    <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-is-compact="true">14.2M</span>
</a>
14,189,678 Followers
```

You will notice in the `A` tag in the outerHTML that `title` contains the number of followers. That's why I'm using it instead of `data-original-title`. Anyway, this code has been tested and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you reference Selenium, this is where you use getAttribute() to return the value of a given attribute.  In this case we want the value of 'data-original-title'.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-nav='followers']")).getAttribute("data-original-title");
```

Then, since this returns more data than you desire (x followers), you strip out the non-numerics with some Java:

```
replaceAll("[$A-Za-z , ]", "");
```

So put together it looks something like this:

```
String followers = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-nav='followers']"))
        .getAttribute("data-original-title").replaceAll("[$A-Za-z , ]", "");
```

You were using getText() which returns the inner text of an element.  GetAttribute() returns value of an attribute, which in this case is data-original-title.

Here's the code I used to confirm it works on the HTML you provided.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/myId/Downloads/stack.html");
    String followers = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-nav='followers']"))
        .getAttribute("data-original-title").replaceAll("[$A-Za-z , ]", "");
    System.out.println(followers);
}
```

Comment: (i didn't downvote, but) maybe the reason is because they dont want to return `"4,000,000 Followers"` they want to return `"4.41m"`  you offer an alternative rather than a solution.

Comment: Maybe I don't read it correctly, but I read '"...I'm trying to get the number:"4,406,048"...:"' as they want the exact number.

Comment: @Squatch, exectlly. i'm looking for the exact  number.

Comment: i tried using your code and i get "Null".  i can get the css but when i'm tring to "getAttribute" i get a Null

Comment: Odd.  I just tried it locally and it worked for me.  I created an html file with your code, pointed ChromeDriver at it and using the code above it worked fine, returning 4406048 in the console with a print command.

Answer (score 0):

you can test that in chrome using the inspection tools and then testing your xpath.

You should be doing something like that:

```
$x("//a[@data-nav='followers']/@data-original-title")
```

This got me

```
[data-original-title=​"1,880,556 Followers"]
```

From there just evaluate in Java.